# Access Windows 10 IoT device from internet

Tags: windows-iot

I have a Raspberry Pi with Window 10 IoT running on it. What I want is to get access to the Raspberry Pi as soon as somebody connects the device, via Ethernet, to the internet.

So what I am imagining is, if I connect the Pi, for example, to my internet router at home, an application on the Pi will send me information about the network or IP address. Is it now possible to get access to the device from anywhere? What is the general way to do something like that?

Comment: The biggest problem i see is NAT traversal / hole punching. On Windows you might need to use a third party service ("SaaS") as relay (Microsoft Azure might actually be the only option today).

Comment: It is called `UPNP`, or you can create reverse tunnels.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with a Pi but networking.

Comment: @flakeshake : I figured out, that I want to use the Azure Messaging service (Azure Service Bus /Event Hub).

Comment: I came here searching for exactly this - please don't close the question because it is only through questions like this (and their answers) that some of us know that it IS a networking question, not specific to the Pi!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a generic network question, that applies to any device inside a private LAN with desired public external access.

You have a few options, depending if this is for private or commercial grade use.

- Manually do '*port forwarding*' on your router, sometimes referred as '*Nat/gaming*', '*pin hole*' and others: you  need a fix/static LAN **ip** for
  your RPidevice; this config is highly router/vendor dependent.
- [upnp](http://elinux.org/UPnP) (Linux)
- [Portmapper](https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper) (Linux)
- Third party cloud service, with a published **ip address** (very off topic): your device 'publish' on a known location and your
  clients access a known place.

On either case, you will need to [find](http://www.myipnumber.com/) (and track) your router's **public ip address**, often randomly changed by your vendor.

Notification when someone connect the device to the internet is a complete different story....

Answer (score 0):

You could implement UPnP.  Universal Plug and Play.  The protocol basically does a multicast NOTIFY on power up of your device, and does occasional 'keep alive' multi-casts.  You can run another process on PCs that you want to 'Listen' for your device, or even search for your device.

When your device announces itself, your devices can immediately see it and communicate with it through the UPnP protocol, or via direct TCP communications as soon as they know about your device and what port to listen on.

UPnP basically allows your device to send a NOTIFY that announces an IP Address and port for your device, along with information about your device and what its capabilities are.

[Here](http://www.upnp-hacks.org/upnp.html) is a link to some general UPnP information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that at the moment the only way to interact is to use some protocol publish/subscribe like pubnub/freeboard. I hope microsoft release some app for android / ios or WebServer inside Win 10 iot to interact with any devices. Win Iot remote client (awesome) work only with win10 devices.